# IBM Worklight - Offline Storage options in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, ibm-mobilefirst

From the following link it is evident that the Windows 8 environment does not support JSONStore and Encrypted Offline Cache: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039422

In this case, what should be my ideal option for offline storage for a Windows 8 hybrid application when using IBM Worklight?

P.S,
Will need approx. ~10MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating applications using Worklight for the Windows 8 environment, you also get access to [Microsoft's WinJS library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465493.aspx), so in this case, where EOC and JSONStore are not available, you should consider looking at the various options that Microsoft offers.

See these (and google for more):

- [Storing and retrieving state efficiently (Windows Store apps using JavaScript and HTML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781225.aspx)
- [Accessing app data with the Windows Runtime (Windows Store apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx)
- [WinJS.Application.local object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700820.aspx)
- [ApplicationData class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.aspx)
- [Difference between Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current and WinJS.Application.local](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/f1a8e981-45e5-49b7-8fec-f454550a152e/difference-between-windowsstorageapplicationdatacurrent-and-winjsapplicationlocal?forum=winappswithhtml5)

Comment: Is the support for JSONstore / EOC in product Roadmap for Win8

Comment: I cannot comment on that. You can request a feature request: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/connect.html